# How to add multiple roles to a user

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to make an update method for my ApplicationUser in ASP.NET Core.

The goal is that I can assign a new list of roles to a user. I tried coming up with this method:

```
    public async void Update(UserPresentationModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            var old = await GetUserById(user.Id);
            old.UserName = user.UserName;
            old.Email = user.Email;
            var oldRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(old);

            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            foreach (var role in oldRoles)
            {
                await userStore.RemoveFromRoleAsync(old, role);
            }

            foreach (var role in user.Roles)
            {
                await userStore.AddToRoleAsync(old, role);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

However when I do that I get a lot of exceptions in the AddToRoleAsync method. Sometimes it's a null reference, sometimes it's an object disposed exception. So this obviously isn't the best way to do this, and I was wondering what a better way would be? Is there just an OverwriteRules method?

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are getting are most likely due to how you are directly using the store.  Since you already have a userManager, you should use the AddToRole methods on there which automatically save changes for you and call the appropriate store methods.  You shouldn't be using the user store directly or calling save changes yourself.